# Help in proving a tautology

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am having real trouble deriving this tautology:

$\forall(x) ((x=a) \lor (x\neq a))$

It is easy to solve this by assuming the negation, unpack the negation with DeMorgan's Law, and derive from there.

I am not allowed to use DeMorgan's however. Because of this I am at loss.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: hmm sorry for the messy writeup.. I did not know how to write this on the web.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck! PS. here you have help to write expressions using Mathjax:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Using excluded middle is also not allowed?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what excluded middle is, but since the excluded middle was not mentioned, I am presuming it is allowed.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in your question what are we allowed to do, anyway here is a hint:

First note that $x \neq a$ is nothing but $\neg x = a$, hence we should prove that:

$$\vdash \forall x (x=a \vee \neg x=a)$$

Now recall  that

> $\alpha \rightarrow \beta \equiv \alpha \vee \neg \beta$

Now isn't there an implicational tautology you could easily prove instead of $x=a \vee \neg x=a$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the first statement "$x=a$" : $A$

and the second statement "$x \neq a$ : $B$

So clearly, $ B = A'$

Hence, $A \vee B = A \vee A' = true$